# Do I accept or reject the null hypothesis?

Tags: regression, linear

M1 : Y ∼ β0 + β1x1 + β2x2

M2 : Y ∼ β0 + β1x1

anova(M1,M2) shows a p-value of 0.0001, so we
prefer M1 at significance level 0.05.

Would that be correct? I thought that if .0001<.05, I should reject the hypothesis M1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your confusion stems from the lack of clarity about the null hypothesis that is being tested. P-values should always be interpreted taking into account the null hypothesis.

When we compare two models using `anova(M1, M2)`, we are performing a likelihood ratio test with the null hypothesis: is the extra parameter in M1 ($\beta_2$), when compared to compared to M2, equal to zero?

If you reject the null hypothesis when the p-value is 0.0001 < 0.05, you can state that there is enough evidence to say that the extra parameter $\beta_2$ in M1 is non-zero. In this way, you will prefer M1 instead of M2. Otherwise, you would miss the explanation of $Y$ given by $X_2$.

One additional detail is that we **never** accept a hypothesis. The absence of evidence is not evidence of absence. You can read more [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC351831/). For example, if you had observed a p-value > 0.05, then you would only be able to state that there is **not enough** evidence that the parameter is not zero (not rejecting the null hypothesis), but you could not say that the parameter is zero (because that is accepting the null hypothesis).

Comment: So it is wrong to say "we prefer M1 at significance level 0.05" right? Is that what you are saying?

Comment: No. I edited my answer to give you more details about not accepting a hypothesis. You could say that you prefer M1 at 5% significance level because you reject the null hypothesis (M2 is enough) was rejected.

Comment: I kind of understand what you are saying. However, why do we "prefer M1" and not M2? Is it because we can't accept a hypothesis plus the null hypothesis being unclear? Is that what's making the difference?

Comment: You prefer "M1" because you rejected that $\beta_2$ is equal to zero, therefore the relationship between $Y$ and $X_2$ is important.